# I am trying to place a git pre-commit hook which can validate my feature files for tags

Tags: git, cucumber, githooks, cucumber-java

I have linked my Cucumber scenarios to my XRAY test cases.
I want to force the process that every cucumber scenario should have test case id as tag (eg @QA-1234). If any scenario does not have this kind of tag then git should warn and abort the commit.

Is it possible using a git hook?
Or please suggest anything else.

I am using Cucumber with Java on windows machines.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [lint-staged](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) with a [`pre-commit` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_commit).

You can configure lint-staged to run on specific file patterns matching your Cucumber scenarios. It will only lint the files and lines which are staged for committing (if you have added only some of the changed files/lines it will work only on them).

You can set a `grep` or a similar command to check for a pattern in the staged files and based on the exit code if zero it will allow the commit and if it's non-zero it would cancel the commit.